# How to convert CCSprite to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, ccsprite

I want to convert CCSprite to UIImage. And I write a simple test project. However,  I find that it does not work. The UIImage can not be shown on the screen although the size of the image is right. Could you please tell me the reason?

The URL of the test project is as follows :https://github.com/HelloVicent/ConverCCSpriteTOUIImage

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution on how to convert CCSprite to UIImage:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/convert-ccspriteframe-to-uiimage-is-this-possible/

Give it a look here and see if it can help you.

This is the solution from the forum (link above):

---

just create a sprite like how you would usually do using spritesheets like so:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"thumbnail5.png"];
```

then use this method to get an UIImage from a sprite

```
- (UIImage *) renderUIImageFromSprite  CCSprite *)sprite 
{
    int tx = sprite.contentSize.width;
    int ty = sprite.contentSize.height;

    CCRenderTexture *renderer    = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:tx height:ty];

    sprite.anchorPoint  = CGPointZero;

    [renderer begin];
    [sprite visit];
    [renderer end];

    return [renderer getUIImageFromBuffer];
}
```

Call method like this:

```
UIImage *img = [self renderUIImageFromSprite:sprite];
```

Comment: Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thanks on comment. Will be more careful about that in the future :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have already solute the problem. Thanks all the time!

Comment: You're welcome. You can consider accepting the answer if you think it solves your problem. :)